# Editing a csv file using a hash

Tags: ruby, csv, hash

In ruby, if I have a CSV like this:

```
make,model,color,doors,email
dodge,charger,black,4,practice1@whatever.com
ford,focus,blue,5,practice2@whatever.com
nissan,350z,black,2,practice3@whatever.com
mazda,miata,white,2,practice4@whatever.com
honda,civid,brown,4,practice5@whatever.com
corvette,stingray,red,2,practice6@whatever.com
ford,fiesta,blue,5,practice7@whatever.com
bmw,m4,black,2,practice8@whatever.com
audi,a5,blue,2,practice9@whatever.com
subaru,brz,black,2,practice10@whatever.com
lexus,rc,black,2,practice11@whatever.com
```

how would I be able to let a user be able to edit one of the lines by them inputting the email of the desired line (e.g. user inputs "practice9@whatever.com" and this allows them to change the values, like they change the color of the line of "practice9@whatever.com" from "blue" to "red")

I feel hash would be good since you would be able to work with keys and values but not sure how to go about it, I tried it with an array and using indices but that is not the correct route in this case, please comment

Comment: A) Use `CSV` to parse it. With the right options it will even produce rows as hashes, names keyed from the header row. B) Use `find` to locate the matching row. C) Use `merge!` to change the values. D) Write out the updated rows using the `CSV` writer tools.